# How to create multiple datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I'm using [Pikaday datepicker plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday) and I want to create multiple datepickers, but my javascript works just for one. What do I have to do now?

Also, they must work all for the same class, for example I want to use `.checkin` class for all checkin input.

[And click to see on codepen](http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/wopWvP)

**MY HTML**

```
<div class="row-1 form">
     <input type="text" class="checkin">
     <input type="text" class="checkout">
</div>

<div class="row-2 form">
    <input type="text" class="checkin">
    <input type="text" class="checkout">
</div>
```

**MY JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var e, f, g = function() {
   i.setStartRange(e);
   j.setStartRange(e);
   j.setMinDate(e);
  },
  h = function() {
   i.setEndRange(f);
   i.setMaxDate(f);
   j.setEndRange(f);
  },
  i = new Pikaday({
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   field: document.getElementsByClassName("checkin")[0],
   format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
   minDate: new Date(),
   firstDay: 1,
   i18n: {
    previousMonth: "Önceki Ay",
    nextMonth: "Sonraki Ay",
    months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
    weekdays: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
    weekdaysShort: ["Paz", "Pzt", "Sa", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Cum"]
   },
   maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
   onSelect: function() {
    e = this.getDate();
    g();
   }
  }),
  j = new Pikaday({
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   field: document.getElementsByClassName("checkout")[0],
   format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
   minDate: new Date(),
   firstDay: 1,
   i18n: {
    previousMonth: "Önceki Ay",
    nextMonth: "Sonraki Ay",
    months: ["Ocak", "Şubat", "Mart", "Nisan", "Mayıs", "Haziran", "Temmuz", "Ağustos", "Eylül", "Ekim", "Kasım", "Aralık"],
    weekdays: ["Pazar", "Pazartesi", "Salı", "Çarşamba", "Perşembe", "Cuma", "Cumartesi"],
    weekdaysShort: ["Paz", "Pzt", "Sa", "Ça", "Pe", "Cu", "Cum"]
   },
   maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
   onSelect: function() {
    f = this.getDate();
    h();
   }
  }),
  k = i.getDate(),
  l = j.getDate();
 if (k) {
  e = k;
  g();
 }
 if (l) {
  f = l;
  h();
 }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it would be easier to create the Pikaday instance when you click, and not beforehand. This way you can add as many *.checkin, .checkout* as you need. Example:

```
$(document).on('focus', '.checkin, .checkout', function (){
    ...// your Pikaday instance here
});
```

Here's an updated version of your CodePen with this idea: http://codepen.io/jpedroribeiro/pen/ObzRQe

In this example I've done it on *focus*, in case user is using the keyboard.

Comment: but it gave me a error: ReferenceError: g is not defined

Comment: yes @recruit_man it was calling a g() function, I've removed it now.

Comment: thanks but now it gave me another error for i -  i.isValid is not a function
how did you remove it ?

Comment: now I remove document ready and it works I guess we have to use without ready

Comment: yes there are some interesting issue but code works javascript error notifier gave me another error when I  enter a date and after if I change a date it gave me this error  i.isValid is not a function

Comment: @recruit_man I've just updated the CodePen. It doesn't throw anything on the console there, but either way, my intention was to explain how to use the same code in different areas. What you do with the date is up to your application. Hope it helps!